# Why does lens include an Iso for fromEnum/toEnum, but not one for show/read?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Suppose you declare two isomorphisms

```
showing :: (Read a, Show a) => Iso' String a
showing = iso read show

reading :: (Read a, Show a) => Iso' a String
reading = iso show read
```

They are unsafe, not every String will parse as an a.

That begs the question: Why those two aren't included in the library if `enum = iso fromEnum toEnum` is?

It is just as unsafe and can't be prevented by the type system. They all shift the burden onto the programmer who has to ensure that the transformation will not break the isomorphism.

Quick example: `under enum (+1) True` will throw an exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Warning: speculative answer follows.*

One difference between the two scenarios I can think of is that it is reasonably easy to clarify when `toEnum` breaks down (quoting [the *lens* docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:enum): "this is only an isomorphism from the numeric range actually used"), while things are a fair bit murkier when it comes to `read`. Another difference is that `toEnum` is a method of `Enum` (and one required in a minimal instance definition, at that), while `read` isn't actually a method of `Read`, and so is, in a sense, less essential (in fact, the *base* docs [explicitly discourage its usage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read)).

On a more general note, when it comes to choosing between exposing a bullet-proof interface and including useful but potentially unsafe or unlawful combinators, *lens* usually goes for the latter, making them available for those who wish to use them while acknowleding any potential issues in the documentation (or, in hairier cases, in function and module names). Given that *lens* is a very general purpose library, this approach can be seen as a non-opinionated choice -- in a context like this, it can be hard to compensate for the absence of combinators.

P.S.: It is also worth noting that *lens* encodes `read` and `show` through [the `_Show` prism](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html#v:_Show). `_Show` is equivalent to `prism' show readMaybe`, and is safe with respect to the partiality of `Read`-ing values.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the excellent comments in the other answer, I would hesitate about the lawfulness of these definitions. For the standard instances, where defined, `fromEnum . toEnum` (and vice versa) is actually `id`. But `show . read` is not, even for fully-defined values and using only standard instances, because it canonicalizes formatting and parenthesization:

```
> show (read "(5)" :: Int)
"5"
Data.Tree> show (read "Node     {      rootLabel=3 ,subForest=[]}" :: Tree Int)
"Node {rootLabel = 3, subForest = []}"
```

Comment: A fair point. The `_Show` docs acknowledge this issue ("This `Prism` is 'improper' in the sense that it normalizes the text formatting, but round tripping is idempotent given sane `Read`/`Show` instances"), so it can also be seen as another example of *lens*' tolerance of peccadilloes.